# Can you customize the definition of Bounce rate?

Tags: experience-analytics

Currently the definition of Experience Analytics is having to do with the user only visiting once to a page.

The client wants to extend this to include time and perhaps more other criteria.  I know I can create a new report item but can we also customize/extend the Sitecore bounce rate or any other default Sitecore Experience analytics glossary item from the link below report in place.

https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/82/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/about/experience_analytics_glossary

Comment: why "Time on Page" doesn't fit your needs?

Comment: Can this be modified at the item level attached to bounce rate?

Comment: I assume that one could modify the Page View Bounce Rate report or at the very least create a new custom version of this report : https://doc.sitecore.net/sitecore_experience_platform/analyzing_and_reporting/analytics/reporting/the_dimensions_and_metrics_in_experience_analytics_reports